# XSS with <a> tag with target="_blank`

Tags: web-application, xss

Basically, I am having an `<a>` tag with target set to `_blank`, where an attacker has control over the `href` parameter, thus possible inserting a javascript tag,  like the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:alert(document.location)">
```

However, this XSS executes in a new `about:blank` tab because of the target setting.

Is it possible to bypass this, and let the javascript execute on the original page with the control of the `href` parameter?

Comment: Why cant they just close the <a> tag and begin a new tag?

Comment: is the _opener_ property available to the popup code?

Comment: What characters (if any) are escaped? Are we assuming proper attribute escaping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.opener` to exploit this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbnz6vd0/)):

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:alert(window.opener.document.cookie);">test</a>
```

Or if you can escape the attribute value context, you can start a new script tag or a new attribute like `onMouseEnter`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this (anymore), JS doesn't seem to execute if the link targets a `_blank` window. Mind having a look?

Comment: It doesn't work on mine as well. It is blocked on my Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [data: URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). Data URIs let you encode arbitrary content (including HTML and JS), with a content type of your choice, into a URL. They don't (inherently) cause a network request; the browser just loads the content directly. In the scenario you have here, you would then be able to use the `window.opener` property (within the new page) to drive the vulnerable site. Windows (including iframes, and probably new tabs) that load Data URIs don't create a new origin - they inherit the origin of the page that they are loaded from - so you should have full access to the opener's DOM and be able to make same-origin XHR/Fetch requests (with authentication/cookies and access to responses) to the domain.

Of course, all this assumes you cannot just break out of the "href" attribute to add a new attribute (such as an event handler, which would fire on the existing tab not the new location), or out of the anchor element entirely and add your own element (such as a script tag).

Comment: What about this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/214450/data-uri-xss-using-wrappers

Comment: @tungsten It sounds like the obfuscation in that answer isn't needed, but yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: I tried this: data:text/html,<script>alert('XSS')</script>, but it requires me to refresh the page or manually load the URL to see the effect

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been solved with new HTML tag `rel=”noreferrer noopener”`

it means no referrer information should be passed to the website being linked (`noreferrer`) to and noopener prevents the newly opened page from having the ability to control the page that delivered the traffic

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="javascript:alert(document.location)">Safe</a>
```